# Decodebase64 initWithBase64EncodedString return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode

I am trying to decode the string below but the result return nil, I tried NSData+Based64 library, sometimes it works sometimes not...
Any help appreciate thanks.

```
NSData *encryptedBody =[[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:t@“EKucvj6yJhrNm18sOECBQBkDCzIHTRS74oQavnv6vXo” options:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

`EKucvj6yJhrNm18sOECBQBkDCzIHTRS74oQavnv6vXo` is missing a "fill" character at the end.

Try with `EKucvj6yJhrNm18sOECBQBkDCzIHTRS74oQavnv6vXo=` to get 32 bytes of data.